# Структура БД для данных парсинга

Tags: база-данных, структуры-данных

Собираюсь  парсить данные. Скрипт готов, все работает. Остается вопрос, как хранить данные в бд. У объекта может быть более  50 полей. Стоит ли создавать отдельное поле в таблице для каждого свойства или просто сохранить  весь JSON в одном поле, а потом работать с этим уже на клиенте?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы потом собираетесь делать с этими данными. Может, вам и БД вообще не нужна и достаточно текстовых файлов

Comment: Если вам потом нужно будет работать с полями по отдельности,то создавайте таблицу с множеством колонок. Если строка будет обрабатываться как единое целое (в основном), то можно использовать json.